# Animating a character in Cocos2d

Tags: ipad, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating an app that represents the pages of a book with animation and interactive areas.  There is one character who is constant throughout but each page has them represented in a different look so I cannot re-use the frames very easily. This character has wings, legs and eyes which all need to move differently. What I am wondering is what is the best way to take them from the PSD into the app? The two approaches I can think of is either:

1. Create a separate png for each frame of the animation and then cycle through them (this would be combined into a single sprite atlas)
2. Split the character into their parts and then position, rotate, scale and move them in the app manually.

The main reason I am considering point 2 is that if I do point 1 then I will need to create a lot of frames of animation for each page and also create them all twice to cater for normal and retina displays.

Please let me know what the correct approach for this may be and if there is anything I should keep in mind.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell total number of animations to be created if you use 1?

Comment: It would likely be around 3 different types of animation, each with between 2 and 4 frames. This would be repeated over a 20 page book as the character has a different pose in each, so this would be around 180 frames. Also including other characters blinking and slight movement, it would probably be around 300 frames in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 sounds much more feasible. 300 frames is a bit too much, but you dont have to load all of them in the memory at the same time. Divide your frames into multiple spritesheets of 1024*1024 and make sure all the frames of the same animation are on a single spritesheet. So, at any given moment, only a single texture would be loaded in the memory, which I guess is the minimum anyway.

You can also do a bit more optimization maybe, by creating separate animations for things that behave the same in different poses. For example, if the eyes are blinking exactly the same in different poses, you can stop creating separate frames for each pose just for blinking. Just take out the eyes (ouch!), create a separate animation for them, and place it over your character's animation node.

Going with option 2 would create un-necessary complications, both for you and the poor device.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I would probably break them up by page and then just load and unload each time a page is turned.

Comment: You can further divide smaller spritesheets. Actually memory is consumed in  2^x times. Like if you make a sheet of size 400x80. Then memory consumed will ve 512x128 as these are the nearest to 2^x. So try to make spritesheets square in shape like 512x512 and use them on need only.